# ¿Porque me repite los datos?

Tags: mysql, sql, base-de-datos, mysqli, phpmyadmin

Buenos Días

Estoy realizando una consulta en mysql tratando de traer un sólo resultado por fecha pero me esta trayendo mas de dos resultados de la misma fecha, alguien que me ayude con lo que le tengo que quitar o agregar a la consulta.

```
  SELECT DATE_FORMAT(fecha_pedido, '%Y-%m-%d'),
         SUM(total),
         COUNT(fecha_pedido)
    FROM pedidos
   WHERE nombre_vendedor = 'Luis Fernando Restrepo Medina'
     AND DATE_FORMAT(fecha_pedido, '%Y-%m-%d') BETWEEN '2014-11-25' AND '2016-08-01'
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(fecha_pedido, '%Y-%m-%d'), total
ORDER BY DATE_FORMAT(fecha_pedido, '%Y-%m-%d') ASC
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el resultado de la consulta y no quiero que me traiga dos resultados de una misma fecha, ¿Que puedo hacer?

Comment: si quieres un resultado por fecha, entonces por qué estás agregando `total` al `GROUP BY`?, debes sacarlo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prueba quitando el campo TOTAL del group by:

```
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(fecha_pedido, '%Y-%m-%d')
```